# Windows 10 laptop locks up on start

Tags: windows-10, freeze

I have a Dell L501X laptop running Windows 10. More or less every other time I start it it locks up - usually this is just after I submit my username and password (I login using my Microsoft details), although it also occasionally happens before I get to the login screen. The laptop becomes completely unresponsive, with the fan seemingly running at full speed. I have to hold the power button down to turn it off, and then generally I'm able to login on the next attempt.

I have tried reformatting the hard drive, running chkdsk (from either Windows or a Gparted disk) and reinstalling Windows. I have also tried swapping out all the RAM. The only USB device I have connected is a mouse, and it persists even if I unplug this.

I don't see any errors in Windows' event viewer associated with the system hanging, so I can't tell what is causing the problem.

Is there anything else I can try, maybe to at least get some diagnostic information?

Comment: Try disabling `Hibernate` option from `Power Options`

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... seems like you have faulty drive. Try swaping the HDD for a fresh one, as you noted your machine is a laptop, prone to hits and bumps, which will lead to failures just like this one.

Do a benchmarck on another OS, from another drive. Reboot into it a lot of times. If it's all cool, then it might be a faulty drive. If you have one laying around swap it and reinstall everything.

I fixed a Dell Laptop random freezes, the one that the last thing you can take out is the drive, swaping the drives and it was all good.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I actually think I have a spare drive, so I will try to do this. Will post back here with the results